# TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, typeerror

I am making a consumer to customer type of program and this error occured with the following code :

> TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

```
    itemData = ["XBOX 360", "200", "NEW"]
    Product = itemData[0]
    Price = itemData[1]
    Condition = itemData[2]
    userSelect = input("Would you like to see the whole information? Yes or No.")
    if userSelect == ("Yes"):
        print[itemData[0], itemData[1], itemData[2]]  
    elif userSelect == ("No"):
        userNoSelect = input("Then would you like to see the details? 
    Command: Product, Price, Condition")
        if userNoSelect == ("Product"):
            print(Product)
        elif userNoSelect == ("Price"):
            print(Price)
        elif userNoSelect == ("Condition"):
            print(Condition)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to subscript the print function. The argument of print has to be written in parentheses. Try:

```
print(itemData[0], itemData[1], itemData[2])
```

Or if you want a list to be printed:

```
print([itemData[0], itemData[1], itemData[2]])
```